# How to add a right click event to an object like button,label,listbox etc

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, right-click

I'm a beginner, so this may be easy. But i could not find it. I want to add a right click event to a windows form. but when i look properties/events menu of the form, I could not find any right click event. Is there a menu or code example for that? i prefer to use it auto constructed like double clicking for click event, so it is better to me if you can show me how can i find that property if it exists.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Button click, and check if it was the right button that clicked it

Comment: i did not get your answer sorry? you mean i add a button click event then i should put a condition if mouse button was right like that? 

if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)

Comment: Yes, as demonstrated in the duplicate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a mousedown event,

```
    private void btn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be my answer.